# Cakephp pagination on recursive conditions

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am going mad on this issue please somebody help me :)

I have this models:

Order hasMany--> Orderitem hasOne--> Product

Product has field vendor_id.

I would like to paginate orders wich have products with a particular vendor_id.

How I could achieve this?

My code in the orders_controller:

```
if(!empty($this->data['Order']['vendor_id'])) {
    $conditions['Product.vendor_id']=$this->data['Order']['vendor_id'];
}
if(!empty($this->data['Order']['startdate'])) {
    $conditions['Order.date >=']=$this->data['Order']['startdate'];
}
if(!empty($this->data['Order']['enddate'])) {
    $conditions['Order.date <=']=$this->data['Order']['enddate'];
}
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>$conditions,'order'=>'Order.id ASC');
```

It gives Unknown column 'Product.vendor_id' in 'where clause' error.
I've tried several things with Containable but without a success :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe if you set the recursive attribute to 2 only if the vendor_id is set:

```
if(!empty($this->data['Order']['vendor_id'])) {
    $this->paginate['recursive'] = 2;
    $conditions['Product.vendor_id']=$this->data['Order']['vendor_id'];
}
if(!empty($this->data['Order']['startdate'])) {
    $conditions['Order.date >=']=$this->data['Order']['startdate'];
}
if(!empty($this->data['Order']['enddate'])) {
    $conditions['Order.date <=']=$this->data['Order']['enddate'];
}
$this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
$this->paginate['order'] = 'Order.id ASC';
```

Or if you want to, you could set the recursive to -1 and build the joins manually .. something like:

```
$this->paginate = array('fields'=>'Order.*',
                        'conditions'=>$conditions,
                        'joins'=>array( array(  'table' => 'orderitems',
                                        'alias' => 'Orderitem',
                                        'type' => 'INNER',
                                        'conditions' => array('Order.id = Orderitem.order_id')),
                                 array( 'table' => 'products',
                                        'alias' => 'Products',
                                        'type' => 'INNER',
                                        'conditions' => array('Product.id = Orderitem.product_id',
                                                              'Product.vendor_id'=>$this->data['Order']['vendor_id'])));
```

Hope this helps, good luck