# CakePHP-2.0 How can i get the username from $allposts=$this->paginate('Post'); where user_id is foreign key of posts table?

Tags: cakephp, join, inner-join, cakephp-2.0, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using CakeDC-Users plugin.

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel { 
    public $useTable='posts';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $hasMany=array('Comment');
}
```

I had to use paginate:

`$allposts=$this->paginate('Post');`

I can get the user_id in this way:

```
foreach ($allposts as $post) {
    debug($post['Post']['user_id']);
```

But i need the username not the user_id. How can i get username?

Comment: you are missing some of the code - especially the one where you retrieve the data from the model!

Comment: I can'tt understand what you are saying. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containble feature of CakPHP hides all associated models by default: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

If you want to add only one field of an associated Model you can use this syntax:

```
$allposts = $this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => 'User.username'));
```

or with paginate use this in your controller class: (http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1232/Controller-Setup)

```
var $paginate = array('contain' => 'User.username');
```

Try the following to access it:

```
$post['User']['username'];
```

Comment: No i can't get ['username'] it's ['user_id'] , i have `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` in post model.

Comment: Actually I meant the part about 'Containable', because this changes the way find works.

Comment: It would really help you to read the docs. You can use the same arguments for paginate which you use for find.

Comment: It's not cakephp-1.3 but cakephp-2.0.

Comment: Nothing changed with Containable in 2.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9319/discussion-between-prime-and-flo)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the recursive property to 2:

```
$this->Post->recursive = 2;
$allposts = $this->paginate('Post');
debug($allposts);
```

`$allposts` should contain every Post and it's belonging user.

See also: [Cakephp pagination on recursive conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561745/cakephp-pagination-on-recursive-conditions)