# CakePHP-2.0, How can i set model relation with CakeDC-Users User model with Post model?

Tags: php, cakephp, relational-database, cakephp-2.0, foreign-key-relationship

For Post model:

`public $belongsTo = array('Users.User')`

And for CakeDC-Users plugin's User model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Post',
        'UserDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'Users.UserDetail',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_id'));
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct. Have you at least tried it before asking?

Comment: Yes, i tried, but i can't get the username for debug($this->paginate('Post')); rather i get `user_id` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872094/cakephp-2-0-how-can-i-get-the-username-from-allposts-this-paginatepost-w/9872394#comment12589624_9872394